# Making installation files

Tags: deployment, installation

I need to make installation file (.exe), but is that possible with batch script and how?
I made installation with some software (Deployment...) but I need to do that with script. I have all necessary files for my installation.

Is that possible?

Marko

Answer (score 1):

Virtually every tool for building installation packages provides ability to include arbitrary sripts to the installation process. Just inspect your tool for this capability...

Here, we often include sripts in our [WIX](http://wix.sourceforge.net/) installations. Of course, user expirience is better when you building installation package nativelly, but in some cases this is acceptable practice (mostly when there is no non-tech users planned).

Comment: +1 for WiX. As a user I hate dealing with NSIS or other installers not behaving very well.

Answer (score 0):

With a batch script, you will not be able to make a .exe (unless you call a .exe creator from within the batch script!). Why not try [Inno Setup](http://www.innosetup.com) or [NSIS](http://nsis.sourceforge.net)? [ISTool](http://www.istool.org) helps in creating Inno Setup scripts with ease and speed.

Answer (score 0):

You can't make an .exe using nothing but a batch script. You can however use a batch script to create the installation specification file(s) and then run that file through an installer creator program like the ones mentioned in the other answers here. Perhaps you could be a bit clearer about what you actually need to do?